# How to search text in pdf in pdfviewer in java or kotlin or flutter?

Tags: search, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

How to search text in pdf in pdfviewer. I want to open pdf using url directly without downloading it. So I want to search in that pdf and clicking next or previous button I want to navigate to that place in pdf.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried "syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer" for flutter. I am getting search result as expected but not able to find next or previous occurrences. Please let me know how can I do it.

Refer this below link.

https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/How-to-perform-text-search-using-flutter-pdf-viewer/blob/main/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the following code snippet for navigating to the previous and next instances in a text search.

**Code Snippet:**

```
  late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;
  late PdfTextSearchResult _searchResult;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
    _searchResult = PdfTextSearchResult();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _searchResult = _pdfViewerController.searchText('the',
                    searchOption: TextSearchOption.caseSensitive);
                if (kIsWeb) {
                  setState(() {});
                } else {
                  _searchResult.addListener(() {
                    if (_searchResult.hasResult) {
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _searchResult.hasResult,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _searchResult.previousInstance();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Visibility(
              visible: _searchResult.hasResult,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _searchResult.nextInstance();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SfPdfViewer.network(
            'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf',
            controller: _pdfViewerController));
  }
}
```

Kindly refer the following UG documentation link for more details about the text search in SfPdfViewer,

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf-viewer/text-search